# React native bottom navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have **2 screens**. First one is Login screen(without header) where I have "createStackNavigation" and second one is Main screen where I would like to have bottom navigation(2 tabs) with Header in each of these two tabs. I did bottom navigation but custom header does not work at all...It's only basic header. Can anyone have some basic example of this? Or can help me with tutorial?

Thank you

Comment: Show us some code please. its the best way to get engagement on a question (also format your question a bit I can't really follow what you're asking)

Comment: I will post code tomorrow. But I'm also confused about react-native...Do you have any example of this "problem" ?

Answer (score 1):

You achieve a custom header passing it through navigationOptions. This can be done in two ways:

1. In createStackNavigation:

   ```
   const navigator = createStackNavigation({
     Screen1: {
       screen: Screen1,
       navigationOptions: {
         header: <CustomHeader />
       }
   });
   ```
2. In the screen component itself:

   ```
   export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {
     static navigationOptions = () => ({
       header: <CustomHeader />,
     })
   ...
   ```

Comment: Do you need both: createStackNavigator and also createBottomNavigation??
Also I did in both way but I only managed to remove header from Login screen.

Comment: They serve different purposes: for your case, it seems the login screen would be a full screen, and the main screen with bottom navigation would be another one. Therefore, you would need a StackNavigation for navigating between these two, and a BottomNavigation "inside" the mainScreen to navigate between the tabs. I quote inside because you don't actually need a component for the MainScreen, instead, you create a BottomNavigation with the two tabs, and use this BottomNavigation in the StackNavigation, in order to be able to navigate to it from the login screen

Comment: I don't understand your problem then. Using the custom header in the navigationOptions it doesn't work?

Comment: This is my code in app.js

`const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Login,
      
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          header: null,
        }),
      
    },
    Main: MainScreen,
    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'screen',
    /*navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#269BB9',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
     
    }, */
 }
);`

Answer (score 0):

This is my app.js code:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
   Home: {
    screen: Login,

   navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
   }),

   },
  Main: MainScreen,

 },
{
 initialRouteName: 'Home',
 headerMode: 'screen',

}
);
```

This is my Main screen code:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Domov: {
    screen: HomeScreen,

},
  Dnevnik: Diary,
},
{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
   tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    let iconName;
    if (routeName === 'Domov') {
      //iconName = `home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
      iconName='home';
    } else if (routeName === 'Dnevnik') {
      //iconName = `ios-calendar${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
      iconName='ios-calendar';
    } 


    return (
        <Icon name={iconName} style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFF'}} />
      );
  },

 }),
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'white',
  showLabel: false,
  inactiveTintColor: '#4C2601',
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#033D51',
  },
},

});
```